# Is Ruby's Marshall format architecture and Ruby-version independent?

Tags: ruby, serialization

I am considering using Marshall to serialize objects into a cache but I'd like to make sure that the same cache will be useable across architectures (linux x86, linux x86-64, mac x86-64) and across Ruby versions (1.8.7, 1.9.3). Will I be fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marshal format is versioned and those versions do not correspond to ruby versions. I believe it is also architecture independent .

As it happens, that version was the same in 1.8.7 as it is today (currently 4.8), so in theory you're good to go. In practice I seem to recall some rough edges, particularly around strings, which in ruby 1.9 have an associated encoding, but not in 1.8.

One drawback is that marshal can be very verbose because it dumps all the instance variables in an object. For example for an ActiveRecord object, there are some instance variables that just track some cached data.